# Installing Farseer Physics Engine

Tags: farseer

I am trying to get farseer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 For Windows Phone. I downloaded farseer although I have not been able to find a bin folder inside of the downloaded files. The youtube video I was following to install it had locateds a bin folder, is this correct? How could I get farseer working in my wp7 projects?

Answer (score 1):

If you've downloaded the "Farseer Physics Engine 3.5" zip, there should be a folder called obj that contains a "Windows Phone" directory. You may need to compile the project first, but in the .\obj\Windows Phone\Release\ there should be a dll containing Farseer for Windows Phone.

Start a new project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and in your Solutions Window, right-click References -> add Reference -> Browse -> Navigate to the folder containing the dll and add it to your project.

Comment: Thanks haha but months late

Comment: Yeah, I saw the date after I answered it. oops! At least the answer's out there if somebody else needs it.